# Como reordenar o resultado de uma query caso tenha um resultado especifico?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Tenho uma query (`select nome from coisas;`) que me retorna por exemplo:

```
escova
mesa
cadeira
garfo
```

Como eu faço para que caso exista "cadeira" nos resultados, ele apareça sempre primeiro, e os outros tanto faz a ordem, mas que de preferencia seja order by name.

Comment: Não entendi, como é `SELECT nome FROM coisas` e retorna vários resultado, pode explicar melhor?

Comment: Conforme link de fechamento: `ORDER BY nome != "cadeira", nome`, traz cadeira primeiro e o resto ordem alfabética. Se a ordem do resto não interessar, pode simplificar: `ORDER BY nome != "cadeira"` ou `ORDER BY nome = "cadeira" DESC`

Comment: No caso a ordem do `SELECT` já não faz o necessário? Tipo `SELECT cadeira, escova, mesa, garfo FROM ...`

Comment: @Bacco era exatamente isso que eu precisava! Se puder postar como resposta para eu aceitar. Obrigado.

Comment: O fechamento como duplicata faz com que visitantes encontrem a resposta original no outro post, e a sua pergunta serve como índice. Aqui a gente evita duplicar soluções em posts diferentes para organização (para que todos usuários encontrem as soluções agrupadas). Quando tiver um pouquinho mais de pontos você poderá votar positivo em todas as respostas que te ajudarem, mesmo em outros posts.

Comment: Opa, tranquilo, não soube como pesquisar, mas realmente é duplicada.

Comment: Qq duvida adicional sobre o assunto, pode deixar um comment aqui ou nas respostas originais de lá. E para outras dúvidas, fique à vontade pra abrir novas postagens.